# Training a convoltion neural network for localization

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, object-detection

I am new into convolutional neural networks and I am trying to build a cnn for localization of object on tensorflow. Currently I am trying to replicate a cnn similar to that of Alexnet and then want to train it to add boundary boxes around objects.

I am however, unable to figure out how to train the network for boundary boxes. For the purpose of validation do I have to feed the boundary values during the training for calculating loss?

P.S. I want to observe the effects of changing cnn structure on loss and training times etc. Therefore, I believe I cannot use a trained neural network.

Comment: There are tons of papers and open-source implementations for object detection (output bounding boxes). You man google "R-CNN" "fast R-CNN", "YOLO" for some of the popular models and their TensorFlow implementation.